# Is there a way in Eclipse to create shortcuts for commonly typed phrases?

Tags: eclipse

It's often a bit of a pain to type something like `MY_LOGGER_SET_CATEGORY(LOGGING_CATEGORY);` That would make sense to assign a shortcut like `CTRL + X + S` which can easily be done in editors like `VIM`, for example.

I was wondering if there exists a plug-in or a feature to do similar in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to 
Preferences -> Java - > Editor -> Templates 
then add new 
in name put for example "mlsc"

MY_LOGGER_SET_CATEGORY(LOGGING_CATEGORY);

then in edit windows when you type mlsc it will be put in there.